# TakeWhile for nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a nested list of time and position for multiple particles over multiple time steps. I want to cut all the time steps off (for each particle) after which the $z$ coordinate goes above a certain value $zmax$.

So far I've been using the `TakeWhile` function but that only returns the $z$ values, not the entire list.

Is there a way to get around this?

The structure of the list is

```
{
  {{t1(0), x1(0), z1(0)}, ..., {t1(n), x1(n), z1(n)}}, 
  {{t2(0), x2(0), z2(0)}, ..., {t2(n), x2(n), z2(n)}}, 
  {{}, ...,                    {tn(n), xn(n), zn(n)}}
}
```

where the number after the letter is the particle number, and the one in brackets is the time step. If that helps!

For 2 particle example:

```
Data = {{{0,0,0},{1,10,10},{2,20,20}},{{0,0,0},{1,15,15},{2,30,30}}}.
```

Setting the `zmax` to be 20 for example. Code used:

```
TakeWhile[Data[[1, All, 3]], # < 40 &]
```

Which gives: {0,10}. This is only for the first particle, so I presume I'd use some sort of iterative process to do it for all, but I mostly want the output to be {{0,0,0},{1,10,10}} so that every field is displayed.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Can you give example data, and code showing how you tried to use `TakeWhile[]`?

Comment: Did you try something like
`Map[Function[particle, TakeWhile[particle, Last[#] < zmax &]], yournestedlist]`
(alternatively `TakeWhile[#, Last[#] < zmax &] & /@ yournestedlist`)?

Comment: For 2 particle example: Data = {{{0,0,0},{1,10,10},{2,20,20}},{{0,0,0},{1,15,15},{2,30,30}}}. Setting the zmax to be 20 for example. Code used: TakeWhile[Data[[1, All, 3]], # < 40 &] gives: {0,10}. This is only for the first partile, so I presume I'd use some sort of iterative process to do it for all, but I mostly want the output to be {{0,0,0},{1,10,10}} so that every field is displayed.

Comment: Edit the question with your example.  A better example should show what you expect when a particle in the middle of the row goes out of bounds.  (OR perhaps the particles are known to be ordered so they always terminate right to left??)

Comment: Please edit your question to include that extra info.

Comment: Then your problem is in `Data[[1,All,3]]` rather than in `TakeWhile`. `Data[[1,All,3]]` picks $z$ values from the first entry, but what you need is (a) not drop everything except $z$-values and then filter out but rather filter by $z$-values without dropping the rest; (b) not only the first particle but all of them. `TakeWhile[Data[[1]], #[[3]] < 40 &]` would give what you want (but only for the first particle).

Answer (score 3):

I used the latter suggestion from @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე's comment:

> Did you try something like `Map[Function[particle,
>   TakeWhile[particle, Last[#] < zmax &]], yournestedlist]`
>   (alternatively `TakeWhile[#, Last[#] < zmax &] & /@ yournestedlist`)

```
TakeWhile[#, Last[#] < zmax &] & /@ Data
```

Although I used the general form for the choice of element (so I could constrain it by x or z) so my actual line was:

```
TakeWhile[#, #[[3]] < zmax &] & /@ Data
```

This approach gave me the new list for all the particles and desired time steps. Thank you for your help!